# Is the expandable usercard available to everyone?

Tags: discussion, bug, status-bydesign

According to the help page on privileges, In particular [Established user](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/established-user), The user receives the ability to see expandable user cards on other users. This appears when the user reaches 1000 reputation. However I am only at just over 700 and I am able to see them.

Is this a bug or something that was changed? If it was changed, should this be removed from the privileges page?

Comment: Everyone can *see* them, but not everyone *has* them on their own profile

Comment: Everyone can **see** them. But you don't **get one** till you reach 1000 reputation.

Comment: What point is there in gaining a fancy feature if only a sub-set of site users can see that you have it?

Comment: @MartijnPieters That's why I was confused, even so is there anyway to make the text clearer for this? I had to re-read it when I got the comments and then I saw it but its more implied in the actual text then actually stated. At least IMO.

Comment: @TheLethalCoder: *when **anyone** is viewing* is not clear enough?

Comment: @MartijnPieters It just seems more implied than stated, of course my opinion may be different to others as I tend to read quickly instead of carefully reading each word

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's not that you can *see* the expandable user cards when you hit 1,000 rep, it's that you *get* an expandable user card.

You can see this by the drop shadow on your profile image.

Answer (score 7):

It's [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign) and not a bug.

If you read the text clearly

> When anyone is viewing ***your usercard*** on a question, an answer, or on
>   the users list, they may hover over ***your avatar*** to produce an expanded
>   usercard that contains extra information. This is also known as a
>   hover card.

The user card is available only for 1k+ users, but **everyone can see them**.

In fact you *don't even need an account* to see the user card of others. (Check in Incognito window)