# Is there a grammar issue with 'See vote breakout, expandable usercard'?

Tags: discussion, profile-page, privileges

In the 'Next privilege' sub-section of the 'Activity' section of a user's profile it is written:

```
See vote breakout, expandable usercard
```

Which seems to imply that at the referenced level of reputation, one would be able to *see* the expandable user card. However, it seems what's meant is:

```
See vote breakout; expandable usercard
```

That is: the user gains an expandable usercard themselves at this level of reputation... I can already see the expandable usercards of users with over 1000 rep...

Comment: Makes sense to me. Although, nitpicks like this will cause Jeff Atwood to find you in your sleep.

Comment: Or even better, rephrase to `See vote breakout, have expandable usercard`

Comment: While we're at it, I think `See vote breakdown` makes more sense.

Comment: Until now that's what I thought the sentence meant (being able to see user  cards). But I was always confused because I could always see them.

Comment: I feel like this leads in circles, to use See vote breakout; expandable usercard or See vote breakout, expandable usercard. Maybe just use: * See vote breakout * expandable usercard (and I'd second breakdown)

Comment: Or we could just reverse the two: `expandable usercard, see vote breakdown`.

Comment: It's `breakout` that hurts more...

Comment: Is it just me, or is the title ironically abusing the semicolon? I'm not a native, but I'd use a colon.

Comment: @Andras As a native I agree and was similarly amused.

Comment: A breakout clone with +1 and -1 bricks, +500 bounty etc. That should be implemented.

Comment: @Andrew See: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/312300/is-the-expandable-usercard-available-to-everyone

Comment: It should be a semicolon in the verbiage, not a comma.

Answer (score 25):

The easiest "fix" is to just reverse them:

> Expandable usercard, see vote breakdown

N.B. Not being in an actual sentence of prose, this isn't a comma splice *per se* but I guess exchanging the comma for a semicolon would be nice anyway.